# Как корректно экранировать кавычки?

Tags: javascript

надо написать функцию, которая переводит двумерный массив в CSV и возвращает строку.
Пример:

```js
func([[1, 2], ['a', 'b']]) // '1,2
a,b'
func([[1, 2], ['a,b', 'c,d']]) // '1,2
"a,b","c,d"'
```

Сделал так, не проходит тест "корректно экранирует кавычки ":

```
Expected: """"text""","other ""long"" text""
Received: ""text",other "long" text"
```

Мой код:

```js
function func(arr) {
return arr
    .map(array => array.map(e => {
        let type = typeof e;
        if (type !== "number" && type !== "string")
            throw new Error("Unexpected value");
        return (type === "string" && e.includes(",")) ? JSON.stringify(e) : e;
    }).join(","))
    .join("\n");
}
```

Что надо исправить?

Comment: Для экранирования кавычек можно использовать обратный слэш - \"
Или можно взять строку с кавычками в другие кавычки - одинарыне ' ' или ` `

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, нужно а) экранировать имеющиеся кавычки путем их удвоения, б) заключить в кавычки весь текст, содержащий запятые

```js
function func(arr) {
    return arr
        .map(array => array.map(e => {
            let type = typeof e;
            if (type !== "number" && type !== "string")
                throw new Error("Unexpected value");
            if (type === "string") {
                e = e.replace(/"/g, '""');
                if (e.includes(",")) e = '"' + e + '"';
            }
            return e;
        }).join(","))
        .join("\n");
}

console.log(func([[1, 2], ['a,b', 'c,d'], [123, 456], ['aaa', '"text",other "long" text']]))
```

Comment: тест показывает ту же ошибку: ✕ корректно экранирует кавычки

    Expected: "\"\"\"text\"\"\",\"other \"\"long\"\" text\""
    Received: "\"\"text\"\",other \"\"long\"\" text"